# Why the get method isnt responding the proper html?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'am trying to scrape my college html. But the html i'am receving is diferent from the page.

The page : https://sistemas2.utfpr.edu.br/login

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sistemas Corporativos UTFPR</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.3a2559ba4017ef614370.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root>Carregando...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="es2015-polyfills.36e383bb4535eafdd520.js" nomodule></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.8ecf09a1095b0f08eb97.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.5555e7ab911504c65346.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

My guess is that somehow the page is being redirect, i just dont know what to do.

Comment: That's the right HTML. Were you expecting to run the Javascript?

Comment: Why do you have this tagged with 'python' and 'python-requests'?  There isn't anything python here and you haven't mentioned anything about python.  What is the code for your scraper?  We need more details to help out.

Comment: you should probably use something like selenium if you want to run the javascript on the page and grab the actual contents of the web page

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your code doesn't go far enough in displaying what it gets back from the HTTP query it executes.  There are `script` tags in the response page.  To fully render the page, those `script` tags need to be executed by the appropriate language...usually Javascript.  Because you aren't doing that, what you are seeing is a raw form of the page prior to the code in the page being executed.

I know a lot about this because I've been doing web scraping for many years now.  There's never been any way that a Python, Java, or any other library programmer can keep up with the likes of the engineers working on Google Chrome, Firefox, or Internet Explorer even.  For this reason, most advanced scraping is done these days by scripting these big boys...by running one of these browsers and scripting them, often in headless mode (ie: with nothing happening on a screen anywhere), thereby getting whatever you or I see when we do the same thing manually in our favorite browsers.

And it isn't just about running Javascript.  There are tons of other things to deal with.  Multiple frames on the page, cookies that have to be kept track of, and lots of other stuff.  It's better to leave all this to the main browser creators.  They have big teams that can keep up with the constant enhancements being made to the specifications that describe what browsers can and should do.

There's a really cool library called "[Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)" that presents a very clean API to the programmer, and uses a fairly standard browser API supported by both Chrome and Firefox (experimental) to script these browsers and extract the results of doing so. That's what I'd recommend that you take a look at if you want to get serious about web scraping.

This library has been ported to Python as "[Pypeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/)".  I don't know how good it is. Our team chose to break down and use Javascript even though we were Python and Java programmers, because the Puppeteer Javascript solution is the most advanced and bug-free, and probably always will be.  Let me know if you get much experience with Pyppeteer.  I'd like to know how that goes.

Comment: I'm a **Java** guy (not **Python**), but this came up under the Stack Overflow `Java` tag.  You sort of just explained it perfectly.  I have typed this response several times this year.  **BTW** - I usually see people recommend **Selenium** (which has a **Python** API) - long before ever mentioning `Puppeteer` although I know `Puppeteer` is much newer and supported.

Comment: Yeah, Selenium is the one you hear about.  I forget what our team thought about it. 
 It's probably a good answer.  Once we saw Puppeteer, it placed so far above everything else that it was the obvious choice for us.  It meant learning and using Javascript, which we weren't all that thrilled with.  It was worth it.  I said that when we chose it, and now having worked with it for about 8 months, I feel even stronger that it's the best thing out there.